# can i use dictionary as a value of set?

Tags: python

as you can see that i am trying to use dictionary in set as a value but it is showing error i want to know that why it is not possible to use dictionary as a value of set ? i want to know why ? is there any reason ? it is not working at all and so many errors are comming So please help me what is the problem ? why can not i use dictionary as a value of set sequence ? but it is working with list and  tuple but it is not working only with set why?

```
s={1,2,4,{1:'fc',2:'tw'},'co-operator'}

print(s)
```

Comment: It is working with a list? Can you show an example of this?

Answer (score 7):

A set requires that all elements in it are hashable. A dictionary is not [hashable](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html).

> An object is hashable if it has a hash value which never
> changes during its lifetime (it needs a **hash**() method), and can be
> compared to other objects (it needs an **eq**() method). Hashable
> objects which compare equal must have the same hash value.
>
> Hashability makes an object usable as a dictionary key and a set
> member, because these data structures use the hash value internally.
>
> Most of Python’s immutable built-in objects are hashable; mutable
> containers (such as lists or dictionaries) are not; immutable
> containers (such as tuples and frozensets) are only hashable if their
> elements are hashable. Objects which are instances of user-defined
> classes are hashable by default. They all compare unequal (except with
> themselves), and their hash value is derived from their id().